# command under docker_exec is not reflecting in front end

Tags: ruby, docker, chef-infra

I am trying to install java inside a container using below chef-recipe. No errors were observed but when I login into container I could not see java installed into it.I know docker_exec is having issues. Please help

```
docker_image node['chef-docker']['docker-platform'] do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end

docker_container node['chef-docker']['container-name'] do
  repo node['chef-docker']['container-repo']
  command '/bin/bash'
  port '1234:1234'
  tty true
  action :run
  end    
**docker_exec 'install-jenkins' do
  container 'First'
  command ['yum -y install java']
  end**
```

Logs and Commands executed

```
[root@sonatadocker ~]# **chef-client -r recipe[chef-docker::default]**
Starting Chef Client, version 12.16.42
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["chef-docker::default"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - chef-docker (0.1.0)
  - docker (2.9.6)
  - compat_resource (12.14.7)
  - openssh (2.1.0)
  - iptables (1.0.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 4 resources
Recipe: chef-docker::default
  * docker_service[default] action create
    * docker_installation_script[default] action create
      * yum_package[curl] action install (up to date)
      * execute[install docker] action run (up to date)
       (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * docker_service[default] action start
    * docker_service_manager_sysvinit_rhel[default] action start
      * directory[/usr/libexec/docker] action create (up to date)
      * template[/usr/libexec/docker/docker-wait-ready] action create (up to date)
      * execute[groupadd docker] action run (skipped due to not_if)
      * link[/usr/bin/docker] action create (skipped due to not_if)
      * template[/etc/init.d/docker] action create (up to date)
      * template[/etc/sysconfig/docker] action create (up to date)
      * service[docker] action enable (up to date)
      * service[docker] action start (up to date)
       (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * docker_image[centos] action pull (up to date)
  * docker_container[First] action run
    - create First
    -   set container_name              to "First" (default value)
    -   set repo                        to "centos"
    -   set tag                         to "latest" (default value)
    -   set command                     to "/bin/bash"
    .
    .
    .

    -   set volumes_binds               to nil (default value)
    - starting First
  * docker_exec[install-jenkins] action run
    *- executing ["yum -y install java"] on First*

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 2/17 resources updated in 11 seconds
[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
4bfcf1f8b52c        centos:latest       "/bin/bash"            7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds              0.0.0.0:1234->1234/tcp   First
94621e057a21        jpetazzo/nsenter    "/bin/sh -c /install   26 hours ago        Exited (0) 26 hours ago                            pensive_goldstine
[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker exec -it 4bfcf1f8b52c /bin/bash
[root@4bfcf1f8b52c /]# java -version
bash: java: command not found
[root@4bfcf1f8b52c /]#
```

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over.

Comment: @coderanger I am not able t find a solution for this. So I am trying different ways to achieve this. In case you can help me than plz.

Comment: You have been told several times that this is not what Docker is for.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this has been achieved.

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: chef-docker
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2016, 
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end
# Pull latest image
docker_image node['chef-docker']['docker_platform'] do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end
# Run container 
docker_container node['chef-docker']['container_name'] do
  repo node['chef-docker']['container_repo']
  tag 'latest'
  command '/bin/bash'
  port '8080:8080'
  tty true
  privileged false
  action :run
end

execute 'Install wget' do
command "docker exec -i #{node['chef-docker']['container_name']} /bin/bash -c 'yum -y install wget'"
action:run
end

execute 'pull jenkins.sh script from github' do
command "docker exec -i #{node['chef-docker']['container_name']} /bin/bash -c 'wget -k -P/tmp/ https://github.com/rahulkumardbit/Products/raw/master/jenkins-centos-7.sh'"
action:run
end

execute 'Setting permission to Jenkins.sh file' do
command "docker exec -i #{node['chef-docker']['container_name']} /bin/bash -c 'cd /tmp && chmod +x jenkins-centos-7.sh'"
action:run
end

execute 'Jenkins install' do
command "docker exec -i #{node['chef-docker']['container_name']} /bin/bash -c 'cd /tmp && ./jenkins-centos-7.sh'"
action:run
end
```